# How do I slice a traceback before raising an exception in python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, exception, automated-tests, fuzzing

I wrote a testing/fuzzing library that allows you to simply give it a function to test and, the library will then generate an automated test to find what breaks the function so you can take the proper steps to make the function highly reliable.

[heres the link to battle_tested](https://github.com/CodyKochmann/battle_tested)

The project is turning out to be a success and it's really useful for doing what I wanted it to. The problem I'm running into is the size of the traceback when it finds a problem. Since this library creates tests in a fully mechanized fashion, the tested function will blow up 5 or 6 levels into my library. This causes 80% of the traceback to be nothing but different calls through the library before it gets to the tested function to show what line in the function blew up.

[heres a link to a small demo that demonstrates how large the traceback is](https://github.com/CodyKochmann/battle_tested/blob/master/tutorials/hardening_filters.ipynb)

My question: Is there a way to slice traceback so it will only show the steps outside of my library before I raise the exception? I'm really trying to make this testing library user friendly and the extensive and unreadable traceback seems to be the pain point for people who have tried using it who don't already know exactly what the library is doing underneath.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You could always use traceback.format_exc().splitlines() to create a list:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import traceback


def thing_that_will_blowup():
    assert False is True


def catch_it_blowup():
    try:
        thing_that_will_blowup()
    except AssertionError:
        exception_data = traceback.format_exc().splitlines()
        for index, line in enumerate(exception_data):
            if 'File' in line and os.path.basename(__file__) in line:
                print("{} - {}".format(index, line))
                print("{} - {}".format(index + 1, exception_data[index + 1]))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    catch_it_blowup()
```

returns:

```
1 -   File "split_stacktrace.py", line 11, in check_it_blowup
2 -     thing_that_will_blowup()
3 -   File "split_stacktrace.py", line 6, in thing_that_will_blowup
4 -     assert False is True
```

You'll still need to identify and slice from there.